# Create Loop to dynamically select rows from dataframe, then append selected rows to another dataframe: df.query()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working with dataframes in pandas. In sum, I have a dataframe called "Claims" filled with customer claims data, and I want to parse all the rows in the dataframe based on the unique values found in the field 'Part ID.' I would then like to take each set of rows and append it one at a time to an empty dataframe called "emptydf." This dataframe has the same column headings as the "Claims" dataframe. Since the values in the 'Part ID' column change from week to week, I would like to find some way to do this dynamically, rather than comb through the dataframe each week manually. I was thinking of somehow incorporating the df.where() expression and a For Loop, but am at a loss as to how to put it all together. Any insight into how to go about this, or even some better methods, would be great! The code I have thus far is divided into two steps as follows:

1. emptydf = Claims[0:0]

**#Create empty dataframe**

2.Parse_Claims = Claims.query('Part_ID == 1009')

emptydf = emptydf.append(Parse_Claims)

**#Parse the dataframe by each unique Part ID number and append to empty dataframe. As you can see, I can only hard code one Part ID number at a time so far. This would take hours to complete manually, so I would love to figure out a way to iterate through the Part ID column and append the data dynamically.**

Needless to say, I am super new to Python, so I definitely appreciate your patience in advance!

Comment: What is your end goal? It's difficult to give real advice without knowing what kinds of manipulations you ultimately need to do. I can tell you that looping through the `DataFrame` and appending to an empty `DataFrame` is not the correct way to go about this. Have you looked into [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/groupby.html)?

Comment: Hello ALollz! My apologies. So, I have actually added additional fields to 'emptydf' that do not exist in "Claims," which will be my own calculated fields. I will then be outputting 'emtpydf' to CSV to present to my colleagues. I thought I'd append the data to another dataframe so I do not have to mess with the integrity of the "Claims" dataframe, but looks like I was making this harder than it is. Thanks for the recommendation! I will look into using groupby instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
empty_df = list(Claims.groupby(Claims['Part_ID']))
```

this will create a list of tuples one for each part id. each tuple has 2 elements 1st is part id and 2nd is subset for that part id